# How to convert R output of getenv function to a matrix

Tags: r, docker, environment-variables

I set a JSON file with keys and pairs like { "name": "NAME", "value": "123" } as environment variables in R for testing purposes. I need to read it as a matrix to give input some function. However, when I read it the type is character. Why I am using environment variables is the R code will be dockerize and the json file will come from lambda function as environment variables.

```
Sys.setenv(R_TEST = 'aws_data.txt')
test = Sys.getenv(mydf, unset = '')
```

The output of test is like:

```
c('A')

""

c(22)

""

c('BB')

""
```

How can I convert it to the string.

PS:The variables will be always changing for each iteration. Lenght of lists may change.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use environment variables for this (if there's a good reason to, please update your question explaining why).

Perhaps a better pattern could be to place your JSON data in a file and read it into your R script like so:

```r
library(jsonlite)
json_data <- fromJSON("yourfile.json")
```

---

If you need to import different data depending on an environment variable, you could try something like this:

```r
if(Sys.getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR") == "test") {
  df <- fromJSON("test.json")
} else {
  df <- fromJSON("prod.json")
}
```